# What are the two numbers in hapi's server.log or request.log?

Tags: hapi.js

When I use `server.log` or `request.log` I see two numbers appear at the beginning of each line, what exactly are these two numbers?

```
server.log(['info'], 'hello world');
```

Output:

```
151230/205853.557, [log,info], data: hello world
```

I'm assuming this is a process id and a timestamp? "151230/205853.557" How do I interpret these numbers?

Comment: `151230` probably means December 30, 2015

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the default Date/Time output format of the [GoodConsole](https://github.com/hapijs/good-console) reporter for [Good](https://github.com/hapijs/good).

It can be changed by setting the `format` option:

From the [docs](https://github.com/hapijs/good-console#goodconsoleevents-config):

> `format` - MomentJS format string. Defaults to 'YYMMDD/HHmmss.SSS'.

So `151230/205853.557` means **30th December 2015** at **20:58:33** and **557ms**.